# Why can this boost::asio::tcp::socket be re-used?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio, move-semantics

Below is some code [from a boost::asio example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_server.cpp). Why is it okay to move the `socket_` member when constructing a `chat_session` if the recursive call at the bottom of the handler is going to hand this same `tcp::socket` out next time an accept happens? I thought that after a move operation, an object was no longer safe to use.

```
class chat_server
{
public:
  chat_server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
      const tcp::endpoint& endpoint)
    : acceptor_(io_service, endpoint),
      socket_(io_service)
  {
    do_accept();
  }

private:
  void do_accept()
  {
    acceptor_.async_accept(socket_,
        [this](boost::system::error_code ec)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            std::make_shared<chat_session>(std::move(socket_), room_)->start();
          }

          do_accept();
        });
  }

  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
  tcp::socket socket_;
  chat_room room_;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is equivalent to doing the following:

```
some_class o;
while ( true )
{
  // assign a new instance of some_class to the o variable, calling o.bar() is valid
  o = some_class(...);
  foo(std::move(o));
  // o is no longer valid calling o.bar() would fail
}
```

The call to `async_accept` re-initialises the socket back to a valid value which can be used. A moved object is in an unspecified (but valid) state, it is up to the implementer of that object what that state is. In the case of an `asio::tcp::socket` the state is an uninitialised socket which can be used for new connections.

Answer (score 1):

And you're correct, the socket object isn't usable after the move.

***But*** the code calling your lambda will create a *new* socket and initialize your variable `socket_` with that new socket. So the next time your lambda is called it's actually a *different* socket.

Comment: I don't see anywhere a new socket is created except in the constructor for `chat_server`.

Comment: @JimHunziker It happens behind the scenes, in the code calling the lower-level network code. What happens, basically, is an assignment: `socket_ = new_socket_object;` (or perhaps a move instead of plain assignment).

Answer (score 1):

The Standard says that a "moved-from" object must be, at least, in a valid unspecified state.

The moved-from socket is safe to use, because its state is explicitly specified in the documentation:

[Following the move, the moved-from object is in the same state as if constructed using the basic_stream_socket(io_context&) constructor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/basic_stream_socket/overload5.html).